# TPS65251_Formula Error?

Tags: power, switching-regulator

[image]

According to the formula, R11 will be 20.1kOhm i.e., R11=((1.2-0.8)*40.2k)/0.8 -> 20.1kOhm.

The outcome of 80.4kOhm does seem to be correct but seems issue with the formula. What do you guys think?

Datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps65251.pdf?ts=1700049617159&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS65251

Comment: I've added the link to datasheet since it doesn't seem to support files

Comment: For 1.2V out, 0.8V Vref, then the top feedback resistor value will be half the bottom resistor value. Looks like the equation is backward given the result they state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equation 25 is wrong; the numerator and denominator are exchanged.

Section 8.3.6 of the same datasheet has the correct equation:

> [image: feedback voltage divider equation]
> [image: feedback voltage divider]

(There is a feedback link at the bottom of each page.)

Answer (score 4):

Looking in the [TPS65251](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps65251.pdf) datasheet *Figure 21. Typical Application Circuit* shows the same values of R10 and R11 from the *9.2.2.9 Output Voltage and Feedback Resistors Selection* section:

[image]

From my calculation, according to the above resistor divider values with a 1.2 V output voltage the voltage at the `FB1` pin will be **0.8** V.

The *Pin Functions* section of the datasheet contains the following description for the `FB1` pin:

> Feedback pin for Buck 1. Connect a divider set to **0.8** V from the output of the converter to ground.

If equation `25` in the datasheet was rearranged to the following the correct R11 value would be calculated:

$$
R11=\frac{Vref}{Vout-Vref} * R10
$$